# Slick slider centermode not working when more slides than slidestoshow variable

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm working on [this site](http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/flexicare/categories/airways/#) at the moment where I have a [Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which is using the `centerMode: true` variable.

I have my `slidesToShow` set to 3 so when there's 3 or less slides it doesn't center correctly. [Here's](http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/flexicare/categories/laryseal/) an example of one that uses more than 3 slides and centers correctly.

I'm using this code that improved things slightly but it still doesn't center quite right:

```
// Set preferred slidesToShow
var slidesToShow = 3;
var childElements = $('.category-gallery').children().length;
// Check if we can fulfill the preferred slidesToShow
if( slidesToShow > (childElements-1) ) {
    // Otherwise, make slidesToShow the number of slides - 1
    // Has to be -1 otherwise there is nothing to scroll for - all the slides would already be visible
    slidesToShow = (childElements-1);
}
$('.category-gallery').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    focusOnSelect: false,
    centerMode:true,
    arrows: true,
});
```

How can I force it to center correctly?

Here's what happens, the large image on the right should be in the center.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any ref. link to the problem ?

Comment: @KuldeepSingh Yes, the first link in the question - http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/flexicare/categories/airways/#

Comment: according to the above link there are two images in the slider, so i believe we can't make it center because its outer container is in center but due to 2 images its focusing on latest scrolled image.

Comment: @KuldeepSingh There's 3 in the slider (there's a text menu above the images to show how many there is).

Comment: have you looked at the CSS for it? and played around with the in-browser tools? I found some plugins have stuff like centerMode which work, but might conflict with some site-CSS or other frameworks and cause padding/margin issues which cause it to be off-center

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I've tried all that I know... the link to the page is the first one if you can see anything obvious?

Comment: Please, can you provide a jsfiddle so we could play around with your code and styles

Comment: @BelowtheRadar This is the example in situ - http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/flexicare/categories/airways/... I don't think I can recreate all the issues in a jsfiddle

Comment: @Rob How can we modify your code to find what is going wrong then?

Comment: @Rob alternative solution - if count of slides < 3 - set slides to display => 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js#L2419) for `Slick.prototype.setupInfinite()`, you'd see the following conditional:

```
if (_.slideCount > _.options.slidesToShow) {
    // The slides are cloned here.
}
```

which means, if the total number of slides (i.e. the `.slide` elements) is **less than *or* equals to** the value of the `slidesToShow` option, the slides will *not* be cloned and the `centerMode` scrolling effect will *not* happen as expected.

So your code actually works, in terms of the `centerMode` scrolling effect; however, to get the correct effect — 3 items/slides visible at all times and with just one item/slide being scrolled at a time and that the active one being centered, you can manually clone the slides (`.slide`) as shown below:

```
var slidesToShow = 3; // always 3

// Clone the slides.
var $slides = $('.category-gallery .slide');
if ($slides.length > 1 && $slides.length <= slidesToShow) {
    var $slide;
    $slides.each( function(){
        $slide = $(this).clone(true)
            .insertAfter( $slide || $slides.last() )
            .addClass('slick-cloned-2')
            .attr('id', '');
    });
}

// If the total number of slides is less than 3, we set this to the
// total number of slides - i.e. either 2 or 1. But of course, the
// 3-slides centerMode effect won't happen anymore.
slidesToShow = Math.min(slidesToShow, $slides.length);

$('.category-gallery').slick({
    // You can find the full code below on this page.
});
```

*The CSS `class` named `slick-cloned-2` is just to distinguish the slide from the original one. You can rename it, but do not use `slick-cloned` since Slick uses that. Or just don't add it, if you don't want to..*

But since we *manually* cloned the slides, we need to adjust the slide index as used below, which is used to highlight the slide link in the *items filter* — e.g. the links below the heading "Airways" on [this page](http://teamworksdesign.com/clients/flexicare/categories/airways/):

```
$('.category-gallery').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var i = currentSlide >= slidesToShow ? currentSlide - slidesToShow : currentSlide;
    ...
  $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + (i + 1) + ']').addClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
});
```

Here's the full code I used:

```
// Category gallery

// Set preferred slidesToShow
var slidesToShow = 3; // always 3

// Clone the slides.
var $slides = $('.category-gallery .slide');
if ($slides.length > 1 && $slides.length <= slidesToShow) {
    var $slide;
    $slides.each( function(){
        $slide = $(this).clone(true)
            .insertAfter( $slide || $slides.last() )
            .addClass('slick-cloned-2')
            .attr('id', '');
    });
}

// If the total number of slides is less than 3, we set this to the
// total number of slides - i.e. either 2 or 1. But of course, the
// 3-slides centerMode effect won't happen anymore.
slidesToShow = Math.min(slidesToShow, $slides.length);

$('.category-gallery').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    autoplay: false,
    pauseOnHover:false,
    focusOnSelect: false,
    centerMode:true,
    arrows: true,
});

$('a.category-nav[data-slide]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slideno = $(this).data('slide');
    $('.category-gallery').slick('slickGoTo', slideno - 1);
});

$('a.category-nav[data-slide="1"]').addClass("highlighted-cat-nav");
$('.category-gallery').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var i = currentSlide >= slidesToShow ? currentSlide - slidesToShow : currentSlide;
    $('a.category-nav').removeClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
  $('a.category-nav[data-slide=' + (i + 1) + ']').addClass('highlighted-cat-nav');
});
```

---

Other option you could try:

- Add an *empty* `.slide` element after the last slide when the total number of slides is `3`. Then, for example, hook to the `beforeChange` Slick event, and move the ghost slide accordingly — or change its HTML so that the slide displays the "proper" item.
- Alter/override the `Slick.prototype.setupInfinite()` function..

But the cloning method I've suggested (and tried and tested working) would give you the smoothest effect.. it's just that, the slide/item is cloned two times — manually by us/you then by Slick later on.

Comment: PS: The cloning method works well, if the total number of slides is at least `3`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the comprehensive answer, that fixed it and have me an understanding of how it works. (I'll award the bounty as soon as it'll let me).

Comment: I'm glad it helped you @Rob. But I updated the code a bit. You can compare the answer's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52379975/revisions) to see what changed.